# What is ` ${CMAKE_PLATFORM_SPECIFIC[@]} `?

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake, compilation

I am not very good at CMake and would like to know what the following flag below means.

`"${CMAKE_PLATFORM_SPECIFIC[@]}"`

Can someone please tell me what this means?

Comment: `CMAKE_PLATFORM_SPECIFIC` means nothing specific for CMake itself. This variable, however, could be used by some script which calls `cmake`. If you have problem with such script, you need to show more details about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMAKE_PLATFORM_SPECIFIC is an array.

"${CMAKE_PLATFORM_SPECIFIC[@]}" are all the elements of CMAKE_PLATFORM_SPECIFIC